# (Non-)Homogeneous Poisson process and their corresponding inter-arrival time distribution:

Tags: poisson-process

When it is said that the number of claims follows a homogenous Poisson process (where the intensity is assumed to be a fix value), it means that we have the stationary and independent assumptions for the increments, and that the waiting times are exponentially distributed and independent.

In summary:

$N(t)\sim Poisson(\lambda)$, then the waiting time between two successive events $W_i \stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim} Exp(\lambda)$.

If the number of claims follows a non-homogeneous Poisson process (where the intensity is assumed to be a deterministic function of time), the waiting times are not exponentially distributed and independent.

In summary:

$N(t) \sim Poisson(\lambda(t))$, then we cannot say that $W_i$ are exponentially distributed. My question is that under which distributional assumption for the waiting time, the resulted counting process $N(t)$ would be a non-homogeneous Poisson process? From the above explanation, we know that if we want to reach a homogeneous Poisson process, we need to assume that the waiting time (or inter-arrival time distribution) follows exponential distribution, but what we can say in case we have a non-homogeneous Poisson process?

Comment: The waiting time distributions for the non homogeneous Poisson process seem to look quite complicated according to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0507657.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your response.